# SSL implementation in tomcat gives message as Server's certificate is not trusted

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, ssl, certificate

I am doing following settings in server.xml in tomcat 6.0.26 and my url is opening with the following message "Server's certificate is not trusted","The site's security certificate is not trusted!" in chrome and "This Connection is Untrusted" in firefox .

```
<Connector port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           SSLCertificateFile="/home/hcl/10.10.105.76.crt" 
           SSLCertificateKeyFile="/home/hcl/keystore.jks"
           SSLCertificateChainFile="/home/hcl/ThawteServerCA.pem"
           SSLPassword="changeitssl"       
           keystoreFile="/home/hcl/keystore.jks" keystorePass="changeitssl"
       keyAlias="10.10.105.76"
       socketFactory="org.apache.tomcat.net.SSLSocketFactory"
           clientAuth="false" SSLProtocol="TLS"/>
```

How do i make SSL site using self signed and trusted certificates ?

What are the proper steps to create SSL enabled website in java-tomcat-jboss without prompting any certificate message ?

Comment: Basically you cannot make a self-signed SSL-certificate that is deemed trusted. You can get free SSL-certificates though, that are trusted.

Comment: Thats fine but How do i get free SSL certificates and add them in keystore ?

Comment: I got mine at: http://cert.startcom.org/

Comment: Thanks NoLifeKing for the link, eventually got my answer after a long time but now methodology is changed by my organization.

Comment: your suggestion worked. Answer this question as you have done in comments so that i can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you cannot make a self-signed SSL-certificate that is deemed trusted.

You can get free SSL-certificates though, that are trusted.

You can get one at: http://cert.startcom.org